# Is there software for an HHVM "bundle" for Mac?

Tags: compiler

The [hack language](http://hacklang.org/) recently came out, and I was wondering if there was a "bundle" (bit like XAMPP, WAMP or MAMP) for the HHVM and the hack language, for easy installation on a Mac.

I couldn't seem to find any, so I'm asking a question here.

Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe reason you can't find any is that at this time HHVM's Mac support is er **Experimental and Unsupported**. So for the time being there is no bundled options or installers available unfortunately.